# Will an image made for a raspberry 2 work on a 0W?

Tags: raspbian

I have an image that was made in 2014 using the raspbian of the time. Will it work with a Zero W today?

Sorry I can't look into the OS version, so I'm sure there can't be a definte answer, but in a typical setting, do you think it would work or not?

Comment: Ubuntu , SuSe , Fedora and Windows do not run on the Pi0 , **nor do any derivatives of those OS**.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have done something CPU-specific, raspbian images should work on newer hardware. A RPi 2B card should work on a Zero. You may have to do some work if the newer hardware requires drivers not present on the old image. Your best bet is to just try it and see. In general, you will want to create a new image using the current (stretch) version of raspbian, but you should be able to boot the old card to copy important data and configurations off.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, as the Device Tree files and drivers for the Zero W would be missing, although you could give it a try.

If you put the image in a Pi2 and update it it should then work.

As this would probably be a Wheezy image, the firmware update may not be available.